# Building Sencha Touch app for Windows 8 (not windows phone 8) Microsoft Surface

Tags: sencha-touch-2, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I want to build a a simple Sencha Touch-2.3.1 application generated by Sencha CMD to run it on
Windows 8.1 Microsoft Surface Simulator.

1-I opened Visual Studio (2013) and created a new JavaScript Windows Store project.
2-Copied the generated Sencha Touch app files to my project.
3-Changed the start page from default.html to index.html.

I then ran it on the simulator, but the application hangs at the blue loading screen with white dots. I opened the js console and found nothing in the log.

Is the approach wrong from the beginning? Sencha Touch team Assume that they support windows 8, but I'm unable to find any documentation illustrating the building procedure.

If any further info are needed let me know, your contribution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the Windows 8 content security policy (CSP).

I have answered [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165397/use-sencha-touch-in-windows-8-metro-app/21169280#21169280) before, in addition to a few blog posts I've written (specific to Ext JS, but the same principle):

- [Creating Windows 8 Apps with Ext JS](http://www.akawebdesign.com/2013/07/08/creating-windows-8-apps-with-ext-js/)
- [First Thoughts on Windows 8, Visual Studio, and ExtJS](http://www.akawebdesign.com/2012/10/19/first-thoughts-on-windows-8-visual-studio-and-extjs/)

In short, neither of the Sencha Frameworks explicitly support the Win8 CSP... but with a little bit of hacking you can get it to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Arthurakay for replying, this solved the problem temporary.  
I still believe that a more 'professional' way exists.
If Sencha claims and affirms that they support windows 8, then we 'the platform users' shouldn't customize their generated code

Comment: Windows 8's browsers are supported... Windows Phone 8 is also supported. The native shell is not. There's a line in the sand there - and it's similar to supporting Firefox but not Firefox OS.